# How to View All Properties and Attributes of a Token

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens

I am new to Ethereum and have done the basics like go to Etherscan to view token contracts, but I'm curious to find a way to learn more about a specific token. The one I'm interested in is PumaPay. In comparing it to other ERC-20 compliant tokens, it has extremely low transaction volume yet the project is solid and is getting adoption by enterprise partners. This makes me wonder how to discern more information like can they mint new tokens on the fly and other concerns I have. Is there a way to view things like this, whether it be from a website or on the blockchain?

Contract Address

```
0x846c66cf71c43f80403b51fe3906b3599d63336f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Etherscan to view the full source code of this contract:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x846c66cf71c43f80403b51fe3906b3599d63336f#code

Etherscan is a third party service which allows people to separately upload their smart contract code to the Etherscan website. Etherscan compiles the code, and confirms it matches the byte-code uploaded to Ethereum exactly at a certain address. It would otherwise be very difficult (maybe impossible) to convert the byte-code back to the original source code.

By reading and understanding the source code, you can then answer any questions you might have about the token, and feel comfortable knowing that this smart contract is bound by the immutable rules set in the source code.

Here is the source code copied directly from Etherscan:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

// File: node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol

/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;


  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);


  /**
   * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
   * account.
   */
  function Ownable() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
  }

}

// File: node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol

/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
library SafeMath {

  /**
  * @dev Multiplies two numbers, throws on overflow.
  */
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Integer division of two numbers, truncating the quotient.
  */
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Substracts two numbers, throws on overflow (i.e. if subtrahend is greater than minuend).
  */
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Adds two numbers, throws on overflow.
  */
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

// File: node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Basic.sol

/**
 * @title ERC20Basic
 * @dev Simpler version of ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/179
 */
contract ERC20Basic {
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

// File: node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol

/**
 * @title Basic token
 * @dev Basic version of StandardToken, with no allowances.
 */
contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  uint256 totalSupply_;

  /**
  * @dev total number of tokens in existence
  */
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
  }

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}

// File: node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

// File: node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol

/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * @dev https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 * @dev Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;


  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   *
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  /**
   * @dev Increase the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   *
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _addedValue The amount of tokens to increase the allowance by.
   */
  function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Decrease the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   *
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To decrement
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _subtractedValue The amount of tokens to decrease the allowance by.
   */
  function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

}

// File: node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol

/**
 * @title Mintable token
 * @dev Simple ERC20 Token example, with mintable token creation
 * @dev Issue: * https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/120
 * Based on code by TokenMarketNet: https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/blob/master/contracts/MintableToken.sol
 */
contract MintableToken is StandardToken, Ownable {
  event Mint(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
  event MintFinished();

  bool public mintingFinished = false;


  modifier canMint() {
    require(!mintingFinished);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to mint tokens
   * @param _to The address that will receive the minted tokens.
   * @param _amount The amount of tokens to mint.
   * @return A boolean that indicates if the operation was successful.
   */
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
    totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.add(_amount);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
    Mint(_to, _amount);
    Transfer(address(0), _to, _amount);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to stop minting new tokens.
   * @return True if the operation was successful.
   */
  function finishMinting() onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
    mintingFinished = true;
    MintFinished();
    return true;
  }
}

// File: contracts/PumaPayToken.sol

/// PumaPayToken inherits from MintableToken, which in turn inherits from StandardToken.
/// Super is used to bypass the original function signature and include the whenNotMinting modifier.
contract PumaPayToken is MintableToken {

    string public name = "PumaPay"; 
    string public symbol = "PMA";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;

    function PumaPayToken() public {
    }

    /// This modifier will be used to disable all ERC20 functionalities during the minting process.
    modifier whenNotMinting() {
        require(mintingFinished);
        _;
    }

    /// @dev transfer token for a specified address
    /// @param _to address The address to transfer to.
    /// @param _value uint256 The amount to be transferred.
    /// @return success bool Calling super.transfer and returns true if successful.
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotMinting returns (bool) {
        return super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

    /// @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another.
    /// @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from.
    /// @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to.
    /// @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred.
    /// @return success bool Calling super.transferFrom and returns true if successful.
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public whenNotMinting returns (bool) {
        return super.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);
    }
}
```